# When is $\phi^* \pi_* \mathcal G$ isomorphic to ${pr_2}_* (id_X \times_S \phi)^* \mathcal G$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$S$ is a noetherian scheme, $\pi : X \rightarrow S$ is a relative projective morphism. $f: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ is a homomorphism of coherent sheaves over $X$, $\mathcal{G}$ is flat over $S$.

We can choose $n$ such that $H^1 (X_s,\mathcal{G}_s(n)) = 0 (\forall s\in S)$.
$\phi : T \rightarrow S$ is an arbitrary morphism. We have the following commutative diagram.

$\begin{array}{ccc} X\times_S T & \stackrel{id_X \times_{S} \phi}{\longrightarrow} & X \\ {\scriptsize pr_2}\downarrow && \downarrow{\scriptsize \pi}\\ T &\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow} & S\end{array}$

It seems that $\phi^* \pi_* \mathcal G(n) \cong {pr_2}_* (id_X \times_S \phi)^* \mathcal G(n)$, but I can't prove it. And I want to know why there is an induced homomorphism $\phi^* \pi_* \mathcal F(n) \rightarrow {pr_2}_* (id_X \times_S \phi)^* \mathcal F(n)$.

Comment: That the homomorphism(not an isomorphism) claimed in the last line exists under very general conditions without any significant assumetions on maps or the sheaf. Infact, the proof of flat base change theorem shows the existence of such a map. Or you can have a look at http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248BPage/handouts/basechange.pdf

Comment: The vanishing of the cohomology implies, using theorem 1.1 here (http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248BPage/handouts/cohom.pdf) that $\phi^1_s$ is an isomorphism for all $s \in S$. Hence $R^1\pi_*(\mathcal{G}(n)) = 0$. Thus, theorem 1.1 implies that $\phi^0_s$ is surjective and hence an isomorphism for all $s \in S$. Now use proposition 2.1 of the mentioned text to conclude your theorem. Maybe just to understand what is going on, one can look at the case when $X = P^n_S$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!